# Set Null works in Sqlite but not works in Sql Server when relating table itself

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

The problem is that "DeleteBehavior.SetNull" works only in Sqlite and doesn't work at all in Sql Server, is this some limitation of Sql Server with SET NULL?

I have the "User" model:

```
 User.Id
 User.Name
```

And I also have the "Partner" model:

```
 Partner.Id
 Partner.Title
 Partner.ParentId
 Partner.Parent (virtual)
```

Scenario:

1. I create Partner 1
2. I create Partner 2 and define that the ParentId is Partner 1 (1 is the father of 2)
3. I try to delete Partner 1 (I try to delete the parent)

At that moment, Sqlite defines NULL in the ParentId of Partner 2, that's correct, that's the behavior I want, but in SQL Server I can't do that at all, I tried innumerable ways and I fall into some errors, follow below:

Errors:
Delete Error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "FK_Partners_Partners_ParentId". The conflict occurred in database "master", table "dbo.Partners", column 'ParentId'.

Migrations Error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Partners_Partners_ParentId' on table 'Partners' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I even found some old texts saying that this is a Sql Server limitation, but it's already 2023 and this limitation still exists? Is it possible to get around this in some way that is easy and affects every table in the database?

I already tried all the DefaultBehavior and none works like Sqlite, I was programming 100% in Sqlite and I managed to develop a system and everything is working, however when generating the migration and trying to use Sql Server I came across this problem.

Comment: Yes, the limitation still exists. There are many ways that just about *every* database system actually varies from or doesn't implement standard SQL and in many cases, those deviations have existed for decades. Welcome to database development.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The limitation exists in SQL Server, the ON DELETE SET NULL works in SQL Server, but not in all cases, when it is relating the table itself it does not work, yes I created the foreign key, after all everything is working in Sqlite, the relationships work perfectly, I'm using Sqlite just for practicality, in production it will be SQL Server, at that exact moment I simply disabled all the "Parent" of all the tables, because it wasn't something so primordial like that, in another moment I will try to make the SET NULL via Trigger, I will update the post later, thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing is [asked at dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206585/cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths-with-on-delete-set-null-really/). The answers explain in detail why this isn't so easy to implement. Relational databases operate on sets of rows at a time, not individual rows. Deleting or updating rows one by one is the slowest way possible.

While SQLite is built to handle a few thousand rows for a single application running inside a watch, SQL Server has to handle thousands of concurrent operations to the same table that may contain several millions of rows spread across multiple partitions. The self-referencing ON DELETE SET NULL has to work reliably and predictably when deleting 1 row in an 1000 row table and when deleting 10K rows in a 50M row table.

As Mikael Eriksson explains in the first answer, `ON DELETE SET NULL` converts a DELETE operation on a table to an UPDATE operation on the same table.

[This DBA question on cascading DELETEs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30446/performance-tuning-a-cascading-delete-with-many-foreign-keys) shows what's involved in the easy case :

[image]

In this picture the server :

1. Finds the rows that need to be deleted in the first table,
2. Removes them from the parent table. That means marking rows and pages for deletion, writing records to the transaction log
3. Spool the deleted keys so they can be used on the related table
4. Repeat 1-2 on the child table
5. When all that finishes, commit the transaction by committing all changes in the data pages and the transaction log.

And that's a single operation. `ON DELETE SET NULL` on the other hand converts the DELETE operation to an DELETE and an UPDATE on the same table. The database would have to both DELETE and UPDATE index rows on the `ParentID` index to get this to happen. Different kinds of locks would have to be taken, and some of them could be taken

There's a similar statement that does multiple operations at once, MERGE. Aaron Bertrand's [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) shows a list of 30 bugs for that statement alone. `MERGE` isn't even atomic and the `UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT` operations are executed separately, which is the cause of some of the bugs.

I'd rather not have `ON DELETE SET NULL` than have a slow or unreliable one

---

While trying to reproduce this I found an SQLite limitation - [foreign keys aren't enforced by default](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) for compatibility with the way it worked over a decade ago. The docs warn this can change in the future:

> Foreign key constraints are **disabled by default** (for backwards compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database connection. (Note, however, that **future releases of SQLite might change** so that foreign key constraints enabled by default. **Careful developers will not make any assumptions** about whether or not foreign keys are enabled by default but will instead enable or disable them as necessary.) The application can also use a PRAGMA foreign_keys statement to determine if foreign keys are currently enabled.

This can seem like an illogical restriction in 2023 until one remembers that SQLite was built to run on the weakest possible devices (microcontrollers, not even processors) where the very fact of checking constraints can cause significant problems. Those devices can easily be inside a car or other hardware device with a lifetime of decades.